# Listen to event fired when the content has changed in CKEditor 5

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How can I listen to the "input" event in **ckeditor5** ? I would like to be able to use `Observables` like this:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.editor, "input").debounceTime(250).subscribe(() => {});
```

So far, I've been able to listen to some events like this:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.editing.view, 'selectionChangeDone').subscribe(() => { });
```

But I don't find the name of the event that would be fired as soon as data changed in the editor. I tried "change" but it only fires when the editor get or lost focus.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Since CKEditor5 v11.0.0 (since 21 July 2018)

What you *probably* need is the [`Document#change:data`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#event-change:data) event fired by editor's document.

```
editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
    console.log( 'The data has changed!' );
} );
```

This event is fired when the document changes in such a way which is "visible" in the editor data. There's also a group of changes, like selection position changes, marker changes which do not affect the result of `editor.getData()`. To listen to all these changes, you can use a wider [`Document#change`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#event-change) event:

```
editor.model.document.on( 'change', () => {
    console.log( 'The Document has changed!' );
} );
```

### Prior to CKEditor5 v11.0.0

What you *probably* need is a [`change`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#event-change) event fired by editor's document.

```
editor.model.document.on( 'change', () => {
    console.log( 'The Document has changed!' );
} );
```

As the documentation of this event says:

> Fired after each [`enqueueChange()` block](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-enqueueChange) or the outermost [`change()` block](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-change) was executed and the document was changed during that block's execution.
>
> The changes which this event will cover include:
>
> - document structure changes,
> - selection changes,
> - marker changes.
>
> If you want to be notified about all these changes, then simply listen to this event like this:
>
> ```
>   model.document.on( 'change', () => {
>       console.log( 'The Document has changed!' );
>   } );
> ```
>
> If, however, you only want to be notified about structure changes, then check whether the [differ](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_differ-Differ.html) contains any changes:
>
> ```
>   model.document.on( 'change', () => {
>       if ( model.document.differ.getChanges().length > 0 ) {
>           console.log( 'The Document has changed!' );
>       }
>   } );
> ```

The last code snippet is useful when implementing features like auto-save.

Comment: Listening the "change" event on "document" instead of "editing.view" works like a charm, thanks ;-)

Comment: Just FYI, v5 is nothing like v4 in terms of data storage and manipulation. We completely decoupled the view (in short `editor.editing.view`) layer from the document model (`editor.document`). Documentation and samples will arrive soon. Stay tuned!

Comment: We rewrote the answer to update it once 1.0.0-beta.1 was released.

Comment: If you want to listen only for structural changes, it's not possible to do this:
`model.document.on( 'change:data', () => console.log( 'The data has changed!' ));`
See the docs: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#event-change

Comment: where shood i put this code? Jezz.. i't most painful product. how to find whole list of plugins? their options? their events?

Comment: i must use input instead of textarea, cause your brothers from webix destroying (recreating) textarea by their wish. cke dont care if target html element doesn't exist anymore

Comment: `console.log( 'The Document has changed!' );` - what exactly here `newValue`?
how to get it?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I see you are using `Observable.fromEvent` which seems to be a part of RxJS and works with jQuery events. CKEditor 5 does not use RxJS nor jQuery. It uses [custom events](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/blob/master/src/emittermixin.js) and [custom observables](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/blob/master/src/observablemixin.js) which are something different than observable you want to use.

So note that:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.editing.view, 'selectionChangeDone');
```

is not a proper way of listening to the event and works most probably only because of some [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

The proper way of listening on CKE5 events is:

```
this.editor.editing.view.on( 'selectionChangeDone', () => { /*...*/ } );
```

Second, 'input' is not an event but a command. If you want to listen in this command execution you can do:

```
this.editor.commands.get( 'input' ).on( 'execute', ( evt, args ) => {
    console.log( evt, args );
} );
```

However, this is a very fresh API, which will be introduced in the next version of [ckeditor-core](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/) (0.9.0), so you need to use the current master branch to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. The answer provided by oleq suits me better though ;-)