# Is there any way to auto add paragraph in every td in the table when I generate table in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I want to auto generate paragraph tag in my table cell whenever I generate the table in ckeditor. 
For example :

Before:

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

After:

```
<table><tr><td><p></p></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: by custom coding it is possible

Comment: oh I see, do u have any example ?
By the way, now I'm using this [link](https://github.com/jeroennoten/laravel-ckeditor) for my project.

Comment: You will have to work with CKEditor's events (when the content is changed). How it works, depends on the version (3, 4, 5). Take a look at the docs, or this thread for CKEditor 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133183/listen-to-event-fired-when-the-content-has-changed-in-ckeditor-5

Comment: I understand but it's not precise enough on how to implement it. (I'm still a beginner)